# Working on a new project, is it wise to continue working on ruby on rails 3.0 or start working on 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Working on a new project, is it wise to continue working on ruby on rails 3.0 or start working on 3.1?

This question came to my mind when I realised how deep I was getting in my current project. Rather than switch over later I wondered if it would be good to make the switch now? or if it is too early?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask yourself: what would be the benefits of switching to Rails 3.1?

You'll have access to the latest and greatest upgrades to the framework such as the [Asset Pipeline](http://ryanbigg.com/guides/asset_pipeline.md) and better engine support. Rails 3.1 is where Rails is headed, so why not make the switch now?

As for staying on Rails 3.0, I don't see any reason to do that at all.

Comment: Makes sense, I would eventually have to make the switch anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I as for me, I would switch to Rails 3.1, if your project is not quite large. I have 3 projects: rails 2.3.5, rails 3.0.5 and 3.1. And it is become hard to maintain older versions. When your project is not complex - you can easily migrate to fresh Rails and not fix any database or other dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I'm at the early stages of the project but getting deep into database work. I'll make the move now.